# How can I use Spring Boot auto-configured beans in XML configuration files?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-boot

I'd like to take advantage of some of the Spring Boot auto-configured beans in XML configuration files, but I keep running into exceptions and errors when I try to do so.

For example, if I have data-related libraries on my class path, Spring Boot will auto-configure a `DataSource` object which I can autowire into my own beans and classes, like so:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:xmlconfig.xml")
public class Config {

    // This works!!
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public ClassThatRequiresADataSource() {
        ClassThatRequiresADataSource foo = new ClassThatRequiresADataSource();
        foo.setDataSource(dataSource);
        return foo;
    }
}
```

However, if I try to do the same in an XML configuration file, I will get an exception. I have been bootstrapping the XML config file by added an `@ImportResource("classpath:xmlconfig.xml")` to my main configuration class. Here's an example of what I'm talking about... Inside `xmlconfig.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK! -->
    <bean id="anotherClassThatRequiresADataSource" class="my.package.AnotherClassThatRequiresADataSource">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

The above will give an exception when running the Spring Boot app, despite `dataSource` being a valid, auto-configured Bean name. I've also tried this with the auto-configured `ConnectionFactory` (with ActiveMQ on the class path) and `EntityManagerFactory` with Hibernate & JPA on the class path, and none of this works.

Basically, what I'm asking is: what is the equivalent to autowiring Spring Boot auto-configured beans into an XML configuration file?

Here's my main Spring Boot entry point is just the standard class listed in all the docs:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm mainly using this in a Spring Integration application, where Java Configuration isn't well supported yet and the core of the framework is XML config based, but I'd like to use the Spring Boot auto-configured `DataSource` and `ConnectionFactory` beans in some of the integration elements.

EDIT: The answer provided by @AdilF works for the `dataSource` bean, but a similar configuration does not work for the `connectionFactory` bean. Please see the following GitHub project for demo code that illustrates this:

https://github.com/ccampo133/autoconfig-test/tree/master

If anybody could figure out how to properly wire the `connectionFactory` bean, I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's most of the code illustrating this:

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Config.java

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:/resources/config.xml")
public class Config { }
```

FooService.java

```
@Service
public class FooService {

    final private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FooService.class);

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Assert.notNull(dataSource, "dataSource is null!");
        logger.info("dataSource not null");

        Assert.notNull(connectionFactory, "connectionFactory is null!");
        logger.info("connectionFactory not null");

        Assert.notNull(entityManagerFactory, "entityManagerFactory is null!");
        logger.info("entityManagerFactory is not null");
    }
}
```

BarService.java

```
public class BarService {

    final private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BarService.class);

    private DataSource dataSource;

    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    public void setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public void setEntityManagerFactory(final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Assert.notNull(dataSource, "dataSource is null!");
        logger.info("dataSource not null");

        Assert.notNull(connectionFactory, "connectionFactory is null!");
        logger.info("connectionFactory not null");

        Assert.notNull(entityManagerFactory, "entityManagerFactory is null!");
        logger.info("entityManagerFactory is not null");
    }
}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="barService" class="app.service.BarService">
        <!-- THIS WORKS! -->
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

        <!-- THIS DOESN'T WORK! -->
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        junitVersion = "4.11"
        springBootVersion = "1.1.5.RELEASE"
        springIntegrationVersion = "4.0.3.RELEASE"
        activeMqVersion = "5.7.0"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "spring-boot"

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

jar {
    baseName = "autoconfig-test"
    version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/" }
}

dependencies {
    // Spring Boot starters
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration:${springBootVersion}"
    compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:${springIntegrationVersion}"

    // ActiveMQ
    compile "org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:${activeMqVersion}"

    // Persistence
    runtime "com.h2database:h2"

    // Test
    testCompile "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"
}
```

Comment: Where are you creating your datasource? Neither your java config nor your xml config has the datasource being created.

Comment: Spring Boot creates a `DataSource` automatically if you enable their `@EnableAutoConfiguration` feature. You can then auto-wire it into your JavaConfig beans.

Comment: For starters your `Application` class needs to have the `@Configuration` annotation next to what is already present. The main difference between the Java based config and XML one is that the Java one is based on injection by type whereas the XML one is based on by name. Instead of creating a `Config` class I suggest moving what is on there `@Configuration` and `@ImportResource` to your application class (or the other way around what is on your `Application` class to your `Config` class).

Comment: The application class is annotated with `@Configuration`. I must have left that out in the post. In either case, if I move everything to the application class, I still get the same problem. The purpose of the `@ComponentScan` annotation is so that I don't have to have all my bean definitions in the main class, so it shouldn't change anything.

Comment: All you need to do is delete `@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration` from your `Application.java` file and put it on `Config.java`. That worked for me.

Comment: Do you still need the config.xml file even though this is a spring boot application?

Answer (score 4):

The following sample code worked for me.

Main Application

```
package app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Config.class);
        DataSource dataSource = context.getBean("dataSource", DataSource.class);
        Assert.notNull(dataSource);
    }

}
```

Spring Java Config

```
package app;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource("classpath:config.xml")
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

}
```

BarService

```
package app.service;

import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class BarService {

    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Assert.notNull(dataSource);
    }
}
```

FooService

```
package app.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Service
public class FooService {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Assert.notNull(dataSource);
    }

}
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="barService" class="app.service.BarService">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: My main class that starts Spring Boot has that annotation set already... so no dice there. I should have been more clear in my original post - I'll go ahead and update it.

Comment: In that case add `--debug` option to command line parameter and check if spring boot is picking up all the configurations. If you can post a github project depicting the problem i can take a look.

Comment: When running with `--debug`, Boot doesn't even get far enough to spit out the autoconfig report. It seems that it is parsing the XML file first, before doing anything else.

Comment: Do you have `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` on thr classpath?

Comment: Yep. Do you have a simple project where this works? I'd like to see it.

Comment: @AdilF the answer is not the answer that works, you provide a link in the comments and request for the answer to be accepted. That isn't how it works. Please modify the answer (or remove this one and create a new one) with your solution (not only a link).

Comment: @M.Deinum Hope that satisfies you :)

Comment: @AdilF I'm going to check it out right now but I'll let you know my results. If it works, I suspect this may be a problem with Spring Integration itself and I'll post another question for them, with more specific details.

Comment: @AdilF so this works, but only for the `dataSource` bean. `ConnectionFactory` in particular seems to fail. I've updated my post with a GitHub project that you can use to test it out.

Comment: For me, I had to add `@ImportResource("classpath:beans.xml")` to my main Spring Boot class to pull in missing definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I used your autoconfig-test sample project and was able to get it to work.  The only problem I found with your xml is as follows...

I'm assuming you want to use the embedded broker.  When I ran your project, that was what was auto configured...

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    return this.properties.createConnectionFactory();
}
```

This creates a bean named ***jmsConnectionFactory***, however your xml is trying to wire a bean named ***connectionFactory***.  Changing the bean name to ***jmsConnectionFactory*** fixes that...

```
<bean id="barService" class="app.service.BarService">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
```

I don't know why you would want to use xml, but it does work.

**Edit:**
I will also add there may be some misunderstanding of how to use spring jpa integration.  Despite the fact the autowiring of the ***EntityManagerFactory*** does work, it really shouldn't be used directly.  You should be wiring an ***EntityManager*** as follows...

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager
```

I know its beyond the scope of this question, but just thought I should add that